# VNC server fails to start with an error vncserver: couldn't find "/usr/bin/vncpasswd

Tags: rhel, configuration, tigervnc

I had installed `tigervnc` for my RHEL 7. After that I forgot the password when was trying to connect via VNC viewer, so I uninstalled the package and removed the `/usr/bin/vncpasswd` file along with it.

I tried to re-install the package and run the command `vncserver`. It it keeps on failing saying

```
vncserver: couldn't find "/usr/bin/vncpasswd"
```

I tried to use the `touch` command and create the file `vncpasswd`, it worked as the `vncserver` launched but can't login from the VNC viewer as the file is empty as it keeps giving authentication failure.

Comment: Where did you originally get `/usr/bin/vncpasswd`?  It's in `bin` so it should have been a program (executable).  `touch`ing a file won't re-create that.

Comment: When I tried to uninstall the package tigervnc-server, it was uninstall normally, and when reinstalled it next time, and launched vncserver it did not ask me for setting up the password so after searching a bit I found this path and thought if I was to remove it then the next time I reinstall the package, the file won't be available and it will ask for creating the file and setting up the password but it did not do so, and I have been stuck with this error ever since I tried using yum erase also but it doesn't launch now and gives the mentioned error again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging around I found this.

I found the link [this](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-tigervnc-server-in-centos-rhel-7/).

You have to uninstall the tigervnc-server

Using the following command

```
# sudo yum remove tigervnc-server
```

After the uninstallation of the package is complete

Re-install the tigerVNC

```
# sudo yum install tigervnc-server

# systemctl daemon-reload

# vncpasswd root
```

root is the user I'm setting the password for you can change on your preference.

After you run the above command you will get to set the password and verify it

Post after all the above command are executed, execute the below command

```
# vncserver
```

After this you will be able to start VNC server and further connect with VNC viewer.